# AccessDenied Exception in Allure-CommandLine

Tags: java, selenium, allure

I am generating Allure reports for my Selenium project.
I did the configuration for Allure-CommandLine in env. variables.
The folder "C:\allure-commandline\bin\allure-results" contains the xml reports of Allure.
Below is the command ran and the exception:

```
C:\allure-commandline\bin>allure generate C:\allure-commandline\bin\allure-results
Command aborted due to exception {}.
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\allure-commandline
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:83)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:102)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:230)
        at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:361)
        at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:407)
        at java.nio.file.Files.readAllBytes(Files.java:3152)
        at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.command.ReportGenerate.getExecutableJar(ReportGenerate.java:102)
        at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.command.ReportGenerate.createCommandLine(ReportGenerate.java:72)
        at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.command.ReportGenerate.runUnsafe(ReportGenerate.java:47)
        at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.command.AbstractCommand.run(AbstractCommand.java:52)
        at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.CommandLine.main(CommandLine.java:46)
```

I have the complete admin rights on my machine, still i am getting this exception.
Tried changing the folders to other drives as well.
The same thing is working on other machines.

Comment: it looks like access issue, try once opening cmd as admin if not and see it works or not

Comment: Tried that too, but no success.

Comment: You have this issue because of **"write" access right** on the **allure-results** folder. make sure the user calling the command have write access rights on this folder

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, but when I followed below two steps it helped to resolve the issue

1. Provide "full access" to the folder  (C:\allure-commandline\bin\allure-results)
2. open the console in "Administrator" mode, execute the command again.